# How to go back to a specific activity if activities are implemented by same class

Tags: android, android-intent

To implement the up navigation, I would like to go back to a specific activity on the history stack. If the activities on the stack are implemented by different classes, it works like this (assuming I have activities A, B and C on the stack and want to go back to activity A:

```
protected void onUpPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Android will pop activities off the stack until the activity specified by the intent is the top most (activity implemented by class A in this case).

However, my app has several activities on the stack implemented by the same class. That's because they display the same kind of data but for different objects. They were launched with an intent that specified both the class implementing the activity and the object to display (either in the extras bundle or in the data property).

Now I'm looking for code to again pop several activities off the history stack until the matching activity the top most. If I extend the above code and additionally set the extras bundle or the data property, it doesn't work. Android always matches the first activity implemented by the specified class and doesn't go back far enough. The extras bundle and the data property are ignored.

```
protected void onUpPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("myapp:" + rootId));
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

So how can I achieve to go back to a specific activity? What intent fields does Android compare to determine if it has found the desired activity?

Comment: "I have several activities of the same class on the stack" can you elaborate?

Comment: I had the same problem and didn't find a solution (other than implementing it manually, i.e. calling finish() in onResume() if this activity is not the one where we wanted to return to). Messy. Hope someones finds a better alternative!

Comment: @VM4: See the question. I've added more details about history stack.

Comment: maybye package where class is located is different?

Comment: Use fragments instead of multiple activities of same class type. Also add tags to the fragments so as to pop a particular fragment easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP), Android searches through your task's activity stack (from top to bottom) using [the following test](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/java/com/android/server/am/TaskRecord.java#252):

```
                if (r.realActivity.equals(newR.realActivity)) {
```

Your problem is that [`realActivity`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityRecord.java#70) is a [`ComponentName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html) (so the above comparison locates the topmost activity in the stack that matches on [package and class name](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/ComponentName.java#240)): no further test is performed against the intent, so it is impossible to be any more specific about *which* of that component's activities you wish to target.

Therefore:

1. > So how can I achieve to go back to a specific activity?

   There is no native means of accomplishing this.  Your best bet is probably to manually implement a form of bubbling [as suggested by @VM4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549827/how-to-go-back-to-a-specific-activity-if-activities-are-implemented-by-same-clas/23594087#comment36150154_23558225).
2. > What intent fields does Android compare to determine if it has found the desired activity?

   Only the component name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I always like to know in detail what's going on. It's not exactly a solution. But all the solution proposed so far require a major rewrite or some ugly tricks. So far I've decided not to implement anything.

Answer (score 5):

As you described, you have one Activity that show different content based on the starting Intent. Well, why not Fragments?

I don't know the details of your applications architecture, but is should be easy to refactor that Activity to a Fragment. There could be a FragmentActivity that wraps all the Fragments which responsible for showing the content. This way you would have much more freedome to handle the activity's stack of fragments.

Steps summarized:

- Convert your existing Activity (that show the content) to a Fragment.
- Make a FragmentActivity (that will manage the Fragments).
- Make the FragmentActivity "singleInstance", so it will cache all the
  "startActivity" requests, where you have the opportunity to add a
  new Fragment representing the new content to show.

You could add fragments this way:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    // ContentFragment is the Fragment that you made from your Activity.
    // Here you can pass the intent that stores the object to show also,
    // so the parsing of the intent would be the same.
    ContentFragment fragment = ContentFragment.newInstance(intent);

    getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(fragment, null)
    .addToBackStack("id here that will be used at pop")
    .commit();
}
```

And you can pop to a specific id this way:

> getFragmentManager().popBackStack("id here", 0);

This solution has a side-effect. The fragments will stick together, so you cannot insert any other Activity between them. This is trivial, but worth mentioning since differs from your current implementation.

I also assumed that you are familiar with how "singleInstance" and Fragments work. Fell free to ask if something is not clear.

Comment: +1 Good solution, provided that one doesn't need to support Gingerbread.

Comment: Thanks for the good solution. I'll consider it. However, it would be a major rewrite of the app. And the need to support Android 2.3 doesn't make it easier.

Comment: Well, you can use the support lib for Fragments. It has everything which this solution uses. Or is there smth that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend storing your data model outside of the extras, using a singleton to access, and refreshing an activity using that data model on the onResume()

Comment: Unfortunately, my app consists of about 20 different activity classes. With your proposal I would need to implement a complex navigation scheme that sometimes involves the Android history stack and sometimes my own history stack within an activity. If possible, I'd like to avoid that. Is Android's activity and navigation concept so broken, that I have to implement my own?

Comment: Speculating here, but I don't think Android was built to keep large amounts of data in the stack history. After accumulating a large history with lots of data you might even see some memory loss even if you weren't reusing classes. Why do you say you need to sometimes involve the Android history stack? Just ignore/override it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you are in `/home/usr/vm4/development` and in this activity you have somekind of Views (lets say TextViews) that let you go to all parent directories. (Clicking on for example "usr" will go to `/home/usr`. In windows it looks like this:

[image]

I don't think Android lets you back into a specific Activity based on extra data. However you can do a trick here. The View (that when clicked takes you somewhere) can have a String tag attached to it:

```
TextView link = new TextView();
link.setTag("/home/usr");
```

Now when you click this View in the onClick() method:

```
onClick(View v) { 
   String extra = v.getTag(); 
   // start your activity with extras here.
}
```

Now you just need to make sure you add the right tags to your links when inflating the activity.

Comment: I don't have any problem figuring out what the desired extra data is. And I don't want to start a new activity. My problem is how to tell Android to pop several activities of the stack until it has reached an already running activity that matches certain criteria (e.g. the extra data).

Comment: Ok there probably is one more thing you can try. When you start your activities use startActivityForResult() now before you finish your activities setResult() with intent extras of the activity you want to keep. In on onActivityResult you check if this activity should destroy self or stay.

Comment: This should cause a cascade effect until only the desired activity remains.

Comment: Sounds interesting. How will Android visually animate it? Does it look like one action or like several ones?

Comment: I've never tried it myself. Now that I think of it I was about to do it but then I found that i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); does exactly the same thing if you know what activity to go to. But it probably won't work in your case, because the activity I was going to was always root.

Comment: If you call finish() in the onActivityResult(), it looks like just one action.